# Jquery onclick Toggle large div menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to expand menu `What We Do` `Let's Meet`.

The problem:div is below the navigation bar and acts like a large menu with 100% width. I made it [working on codepen](http://codepen.io/sachya/pen/QjWBya) somehow but found solution to be naive. How can i have robust menu design where i can automatically get onclick toggle over every li element inside the ul with div class as target. 
Secondary, i can't manage to change the background-color li element on click.

```js
$( ".sub-menu1" ).click(function() {
  $( ".sub-menu-list" ).toggle();
  $( ".sub-menu-list1" ).hide();

});
$( ".sub-menu2" ).click(function() {
  $( ".sub-menu-list1" ).toggle();
  $( ".sub-menu-list" ).hide();
});
```

```css
header.header {
  color: #111;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  width: 100%;
  displaY: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight:600;
}

header .header-item {
  align-self: center;
}
header .header-items {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 3rem 0 0;
}
header li.header-items:last-child {
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-item">
    <li class='header-items'>Hi!</li>
    <li class='header-items'><a class="sub-menu1" href="#" > What We Do</a></li>
    <li class='header-items'><a class="sub-menu2" href="#">Let's Meet</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="sub-menu-list" onfocusout="closed()">
  <div str-row>

    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>4</p>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <form class="ci_form" action='' method='post'>
    <div str-row>
      <div str-xs="12" str-sm="4" str-sm-offset="2">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="fname">
      </div>
      <div str-xs="12" str-sm="4">
        <input type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number" name="phone">
      </div>
    </div>
    <section str-row>
      <div str-sm="4" str-sm-offset="2" str-xs="12">
        
      </div>
      <div str-sm="4" str-xs="12">
        <select id="fieldselector">
          <option value="0">Select Reason to Contact</option>
          
        </select>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div str-row>
      <div str-xs="12" str-sm="8" str-sm-offset="2">
        <button class="button submission">Get Quote</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<section class="sub-menu-list1">
  <div str-row>

    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" str-xs="12" str-sm>
      <a href="#"><img class="responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
        <p>4</p>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  
</section>
```

The code snippet is not looking accurate but can help to some extent. Codepen demo looks far better. link given above.

Comment: Use `data-*` attributes. Check [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvvvVw)

Comment: Thanks, can you help something about color change of li element? i am clueless, tried adding class but no idea how to toggle it with menus

Comment: @SachinKanungo, `tried adding class but no idea how to toggle it with menus`. can you show what you tried ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/sachya/pen/eppZJp I can't seem to change the background of parent level menu onclick.